# C# Console application, How to calculate Mobile Bill for any duration?

Tags: c#, algorithm, datetime, billing

Lets say We have two billing period for our mobile call, if we call between 0-12, then call rate is 1$/Min & if we call between 12-24, then the rate is 2$/min. A call can starts at any time & lasts for any duration. I need to calculate the bill for the call duration. I'm getting it difficult to work with the datetime type. Also I need a better algorithm to calculate the bill. I'm trying something like this:

```
DateTime StartTime, EndTime;
        decimal Bill = 0;
        decimal RemainingDuration;


        StartTime = DateTime.Now;

        EndTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2.5);

        var Duration = (EndTime.ToString("H:mm") - StartTime.ToString("H:mm"));

        if (StartTime.Hour > 0 && StartTime.Hour < 12)
        {
            //var RemainingTime = 12.00 - StartTime;
            //if (Duration < RemainingTime)
            //{
            //    Bill = (Duration * 60) * 1;
            //    Console.WriteLine(Bill);
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    RemainingDuration = Duration - RemainingTime;
            //    Bill = ((RemainingTime * 60) * 1) + ((RemainingDuration * 60) * 2);
            //    Console.WriteLine(Bill);
            //}

        }
        else if (StartTime.Hour > 12 && StartTime.Hour < 24)
        {
            //var RemainingTime = 24.00 - StartTime.Hour;

            //if (Duration < RemainingTime)
            //{
            //    Bill = (Duration * 60) * 2;
            //    Console.WriteLine(Bill);
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    RemainingDuration = Duration - RemainingTime;
            //    Bill = ((RemainingTime * 60) * 2) + ((RemainingDuration * 60) * 1);
            //    Console.WriteLine(Bill);
            //}
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

There are some errors for type miss match. the errors are not my prime concern here, I wrote this code assuming the call duration can be maximum 24 hours. I need to write it for unlimited duration. Also Getting hard time to convert types. Code sample would really help. thanks

Comment: **Read the error message**.

Comment: You souldn't use var

Comment: What do you think it means to subtract two strings.

Comment: the errors is not my prime concern here, I wrote this code assuming the call duration can be maximum 24 hours. I need to write it for unlimited duration. Also Getting hard time to convert types. Code sample would really help. thanks.

Comment: you can see, I commented out those portion, I was trying different type of conversion. What I need, is to extract the time part from the datetime type & then compare between two time part. How can I do that?

Comment: @deKajoo: What? I don't know where you heard that from, but it's complete nonsense.

Comment: @Jon Maybe that was a bit too short : IMO var makes sense when you clearly know what is comes from like in `var a= new A();`
But since he seems new to c# he shouldn't use them at all in the first place.

Comment: @deKajoo as long as `var` is nothing but compiler's syntax sugar - your sentence is nonsense

Comment: Guys, cool down, I know what var means & string can't be subtracted. I'm not a newbie in C#, Type mismatch is not a big deal as I mentioned, I needed a solution for unlimited call duration. I needed a algorithm to calculate that kind of bill, anyone can give me any idea about that? Otherwise thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a type mismatch since you're converting the DateTime to strings before attempting arithmetic on them. As for the algorithm, well, of course there are thousands of ways you could do it, but here is a simple example that solves your 24 hour problem and perhaps gives you some more ideas.

```
decimal bill = 0;            

DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2.5);
DateTime timeNow = startTime;

while (timeNow <= endTime)
{                
    decimal rate = (timeNow.Hour >= 12 && timeNow.Hour <= 24) ? 2 : 1;                
    bill = bill + rate;
    Console.WriteLine("{0:HH:mm}, rate: ${1:#,0.00}, bill: ${2:#,0.00}", timeNow, rate, bill);
    timeNow = timeNow.AddMinutes(1);
}

Console.WriteLine("Bill: {0:HH:mm} to {1:HH:mm}, {2:#,0} mins, ${3:#,0.00}", startTime, endTime, (endTime - startTime).TotalMinutes, bill);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thanks Mate, Very well written. I will try to extend it for unlimited duration. I'm Marking your answer as correct.